How can I save the selected theme in localhost on my website?
So I currently have a website designed with two themes, the layout is exactly the same but many elements were changed by color and design, as well as a new site image displayed. I achieved this simply by creating two css files. The default layout is set as the style for all visitors, and the second is achieved by creating a link with a script to switch css applied to the site by clicking on it, which I created as a button that is itself styled specifically in css. The buttons allow one to switch to the second theme and back to the default theme, both buttons display regardless of the chosen theme. The buttons are next to each other, there is no toggle switch or image or dropdown list, they appear as two links. Here are the codes for those.
Style:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blue.css">
Buttons:
<button class="button2" onclick="toggleTheme('blue.css')">Blue</button> <button class="button2" onclick="toggleTheme('grey.css')">Grey</button>

The issue that I want to resolve is that despite clicking to change the theme to the "grey" and changing the theme on that page, it resets back to the default blue once the visitor clicks to another page, and I would like the theme to stay unless the visitor clicks back to "blue". I know I need a script for this but I haven't had much luck finding the solution, and additionally run into many tutorials saying to use :root to achieve this but I have way too many custom changes in the css files including three different types of links, four headers, custom colors for selection and scrollbar, simply so much going on and I haven't a clue how to ensure it works if I alter the css files. I think a script would make this easier to achieve.
And to be honest my knowledge of how to use scripts is severely lacking. Even if I read similar questions I am really confused.
Thanks for any help
Would this code be useful? How do I make this work? When I add scripts the toggle ceases to function at all.
<script>
// Function to toggle theme and save choice in sessionStorage
function toggleTheme(themeFileName) {
    // Set the href attribute of the stylesheet to the chosen theme
    document.getElementById('theme-style').setAttribute('href', themeFileName);
    
    // Save the chosen theme in sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedTheme', themeFileName);
}

// Function to apply the theme from sessionStorage on page load
window.onload = function() {
    // Check if a theme is stored in sessionStorage
    var selectedTheme = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedTheme');
    
    // If a theme is stored, apply it
    if (selectedTheme) {
        document.getElementById('theme-style').setAttribute('href', selectedTheme);
    }
};


You need to share some code that you have tried.

Your terminology is incorrect. You should be asking about saving data in local storage. ("localhost" is a different concept completely.) Have a look at this article.

You need to make a function to save user choice and another to check if there is any saved choices, if you're not aware of that you need to learn more about Local Storage, so you can save items locally, also you need to understand how to use readyState, readystatechange, DOMContentLoaded

@Yash Every javascript I could find about this I just copied and pasted into the script tag, but I don't know what to tell you because I don't understand javascript. Every code I find is trying to switch themes with a toggle switch, or trying to change just background and text color, or creating a dropdown list. None of it applies to the buttons I used with a css file, so it's not doing anything of course. It works now as it does now without any script at all besides the onclick toggle theme part, which is not in the script tag.

Thanks Brett and Burham I will look into all of those

@mango just edit your toggleTheme function, so it can do all the work for saving the current theme locally using localeStorage function, then create anew function that checks the localStorage for any saved theme before loading content

what element is this #theme-style? something like <link id="theme-style" href="..." />?

@GrafiCode I don't know. I copied the code somewhere and don't understand how to use it. Tbh I am just going to give up.

The code you've provided right at the bottom has several issues:

You didn't show all the code, so we don't know what could be possibly happening.
I recommend using localStorage, rather than sessionStorage. Session storage seems to be for sessions, as the name suggests :D
I recommend using addEventListener(...), rather than window.onload = ....  So you can have multiple load events, and the scripts at client side doesn't intercept with your website code.

Also, as I've read your post, I think you want to modify styles of another website. Maybe you have multiple script files, and some other one changes the theme? Or you need to put !important, after the property value in your CSS stylesheet (so other stylesheets doesnt override your properties)?
By the way, try looking at your website in Guest mode. I mean, with extensions disabled. Maybe some of your extensions are intercepting with your code.
I recommend using this code:
/**
 * Sets the theme to the specified one.
 * @param {String} theme URL address to the CSS stylesheet of the theme.
 */
function toggleTheme(theme) {
   document.querySelector("#theme-style").href = theme;
   localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
   var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
   if (theme)
      document.querySelector("#theme-style").href = theme;
}, true);

A brief explanation of what it does: the same as your does, but uses localStorage.
A longer explanation of what it does:

The function toggleTheme changes the href attribute of the #theme-style element, and then also sets the theme value in localStorage to href.
When the site loads, changes the href attribute of the #theme-style element, to the one saved in localStorage (theme item).

Oh! I almost forgot. Try developer tools (F12 / Ctrl+Shift+I) for debugging your website. You probably wanna check the Application tab. It contains information about local storage, session storage, cookies and lots of other things.
EDIT: Also, your JavaScript code may be in a section - for example, in a function, if statement, or something similar. If so, the button onclick attribute may be unable to call your function - because it's not visible globally (in the global scope).

this answer is useless

Sorry but you would have to explain this like I am 3 years old because it sounds like a foreign language to me.
